# How to increase parallel-processing speed over compute-nodes on linux cluster?

Tags: linux, shell, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, numerical-methods

Below is the code relevant to the question I am asking. I am working with a cluster that has 13 compute-nodes and 1 top node (a.k.a. main node). The top node is the node that connects all of the users therefore it is alloted more memory so it can run faster. I would like to increase the speed of the other nodes however, because they run quite slowly comparative to the top node, and I would like to increase their speed without making any server and/or hardward adjustments. Considering these constraints, I am wondering whether or not there is a way to accomplish faster computing based of how I kick-off the simulations on the compute nodes. Currently, to kick off a part of the simulation with certain initial conditions, (this can be seen below) I simply ssh onto the compute node and then initiate my simulation. Is there a better way to do this that would increase computation speed (I am thinking there might be something faster than ssh?). Any help would be greatly appreciated.... I understand there is something called MPI, but for the project I am working on I do not believe that implementing MPI would be necessary if I can just increase the computational speed of the ssh'd nodes... Thanks.

**./NodeHopper.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
#NodeHopper uses shell script to run psuedo-parallel computing over a cluster

#The top node is not named sequentially, so its not in the proceeding loop.
#Instead, it is given the node value 13 for computations later

export PROG=13
nohup ./ParaCage.sh & #Runs ParaCage.sh on the main node for the cluster

#Does other nodes sequentially #0 through 12
for i in {0..12}
do
  export PROG=$i 
  #PROG is passed into ./ParaCage.sh and tells ./ParaKeet.sh which initial conditions  
  #to use for the simulation.
  ssh compute-0-$i PROG=$PROG ./ParaCage.sh &
  sleep 1
done
```

**./ParaCage.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Tunneling to Node:"
echo $PROG
echo "Complete"

cd multichmoII/multichmo$PROG/chmo/
./ParaKeet.sh
```

**ParaKeet.sh**

ParaKeet.sh is a program to run a simulation with different initial conditions that are based off which node is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am wondering whether or not there is a way to accomplish faster computing based of how I kick-off the simulations on the compute nodes.

Well, your SSH kick-off script has a `sleep` in it. You could try removing that.

SSH does have some overhead (spawns a new process for every "message"; only does encrypted connections, even though you may not need it). So you could replace SSH with a proper distributed task queue. There are a lot of alternatives, including [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) and [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque). In fact, you can easily write your own with Redis or 0MQ.

But don't bother replacing SSH unless your jobs are short-lived. (i.e. shaving off a 100ms from a 1 minute job isn't that useful.)

> I would like to increase the speed of the other nodes

There is no silver bullet: Your best bet is to put on your detective hat and try to figure out where your bottlenecks are:

1) Look at "top" on the other nodes. Are all the CPUs maxed out? (If not, you may want to spawn one task per CPU instead of one task per box, or rewrite your task to use multiple threads.)

2) Is each node pulling files from a central (and overloaded) NFS server? (If so, it might be faster to copy/cache files locally, or have multiple servers to pull data from, or use bittorrent, etc..)

3) Even if your CPU is maxed out, is it because you wrote in a scripting language? First, optimize your algorithms, then try rewriting in a faster language like [golang](http://golang.org/). (And get multithreading for free.)

Remember, premature optimization is the root of all evil. You should always measure, and then try to estimate how much faster you can make each part. Pick the low-hanging fruit first, and leave the smallest gains for last. (You may never get around to the small gains because something more important will pop up.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should move from bash to python and use there multithreading ? Then you can ssh to the nodes in parallel and this can increase the speed.

Comment: Isn't that what this program is doing? Looking at my data I am starting to doubt that.. The same conditions are being run for all of the compute nodes, and the head node is doing just fine.... Are they really not running in parallel? I though that by kicking them off this way they would be....

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature of the simulation you're running, it might be better to divide the simulation itself up - and parallel process that.  This would be the case if each node just isn't powerful enough to run the program effectively themselves.  On the other hand, if the simulation is easily decomposed into parallel threads---each using much less memory / processor-power---then each node might be well suited to handle each component you assign it.